# Dropzone.js inside another PHP form

Tags: php, jquery, dropzone.js

Despite there's some documentation, there are very few real examples on how to use it.

For example: I want to include Dropzone inside my existing form that adds a product with title, description and photos.

Dropzone itself works as a form. It would be nice to use Dropzone just to preview and validate image type and size, but let the main form submit all the data. How should I do it?

This would be the idea (however, I shouldn't include a form inside a form):

```
<form action="products/add.php" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <legend>Add product</legend>
    </div>

    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="input-title" class="form-control">

    <label for="description">Description</label>
    <input type="text" name="description" id="input-description" class="form-control">

    <form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id>
      <div class="dropzone-previews"></div>
    </form>

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 15):

Please try the following. You have to "load" dropzone programmatically as the creator explains [here](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#create-dropzones-programmatically)

```js
 Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {

   $("div#my-awesome-dropzone").dropzone({
     url: "/file/post"
   });

 });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.0.1/dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.0.1/min/basic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.0.1/dropzone.js"></script>


<form action="products/add.php" method="POST" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <legend>Add product</legend>
  </div>

  <label for="title">Title</label>
  <input type="text" name="title" id="input-title" class="form-control">

  <label for="description">Description</label>
  <input type="text" name="description" id="input-description" class="form-control">

  <div class="dropzone dropzone-previews" id="my-awesome-dropzone"></div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: what is autodiscover?

Comment: @Limon When Dropzone starts, it scans the whole document, and looks for elements with the dropzone class. It then creates an instance of Dropzone for every element found. If you, later on, create a Dropzone instance yourself, you'll create a second Dropzone which causes an error.

Comment: you are awsome!

Comment: This doesn't actually post the form and upload data together in one POST request.